# How to download the file to local machine from an application hosted in a server using python and jQuery

Tags: python, jquery

Im working on an application where I take few details from a UI and connect to a backend API to fetch some data. Once I fetch the data, I need to write it to a file in the local machine. I used something like this

```
def csv_writer(<few_params>):
    output_file = "/tmp/{}_{}.csv".format(xyz,datetime.now())
    if <something> == "thing":
        headers = ["s_no", "id"] + keys
    else:
        headers = ["s_no", "feature_id"] + keys
    with open(output_file, "w", encoding="utf8") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(headers)
```

This is working fine when I ran the application on a localhost, but now once that is deployed in higher environments, a dialog box is being showed that the file is downloaded to tmp location but unable to find it in my local machine. Is the file getting downloaded to tmp location of the server where the application is hosted ?

How can I download the file into my local machine even if the application is hosted in any of the environment ?

Note : Above code is written in Python.

Comment: This appears to write the file locally via Python. So when run on a server or remote location, the file is being created locally on the server, written to, and closed. What were you expecting to have happen?

Comment: normal...is 'tmp' a folder (did you created it?), do you have write reight on it?

Comment: Yes I have right to create and write data into tmp folder. @user1438644

Comment: @Twisty, Now I need to get that file downloaded to my local machine.